# Feedback request: Is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

If not, can it be brought on topic?

[Who planted the assembly in Rome to whom Paul wrote "Romans"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34528/who-planted-the-assembly-in-rome-to-whom-paul-wrote-romans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [help center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) clearly states that questions about **historical context (with regards to a particular text)** are **on** topic.

In my view, the close votes are a symptom of an unfortunate formulation of the close reason: the close reason is more restrictive than the help center. For discussion, see: [Can we reformulate the "Specific Bible passage" close reason?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3502/2672)

Comment: The question fails the "particular text" qualification, because it's really got nothing to do with Rom 1:10, and could be equally asked about any other verse in the NT which mentions Rome.

Comment: @curiousdannii it relates to Romans as a whole.